# SQL - select processes that were cancelled with a date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table, which showing statuses of processes ( especially i searching canceled processes), there is no sorting out there. I want to select all of them that they were resume again. I want to do this "sticking a specific date to canceled process and check if there are still other statuses after the cancellation status.

Example:

[id] [moddate] [status] 
 
 1   01/01/17  started 
 1   02/01/17  waiting for signature
 1   04/01/17  canceled
 **1   09/01/17  delivery documents

 1   11/01/17  complited** <-- I want to select these statuses, (Canceled and then somehow resumed)

I got something like this on start:

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE
WHERE APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL LIKE 'CANCELED%'
AND  APPLICATIONDATE BETWEEN '17/01/01' AND '17/07/24';
```

Comment: mysql or (MS) SQL-Server?

Comment: @Jens SQL Developer

Comment: @Matt . . . I think SQL developer is associated with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

One method for doing this uses window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             max(case when status = 'canceled' then applicationdate end) over (partition by id) as canceldate
      from database
      where applicationdate between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-07-24'
     ) d
where applicationdate > canceldate;
```